# Phylogenetic generalized linear models with no. of successes/failures as response in r

Tags: r, logistic-regression, phylogeny

I have a plant dataset containing information about how often each plant species (n=550) succeeds or fails to do something, i.e. the number of successes and the number of failures. The dataset also contains data on each plant species' characteristics such as seed size, competitive ability, maximum dispersal distance etc. Most explanatory variables are continuous, but one is binary (presence of mycorrhiza or not). Normally, in order to analyse the degree to which the number of times a plant succeeds in doing something relates to it's characteristics I guess you would use a GLM with family binomial in a manner like this:

```
my.model <- glm(cbind(no.of.successes,no.of.failures) ~ seed.size + max.dispersal.distance 
            + competitive.ability, data=data, family="binomial")
```

However, as some of these traits may be bound to the plants' evolutionary history, I would like to take account for the bias that may arise as a consequence of that. Therefore I would like to include phylogenetic information in my models. When you have a continuous response you could use a PGLS (caper package), but for my purpose I guess a logistic regression like the above is more appropriate. One method could be to use the phyloglm function in the phylolm package. There are also alternatives, but common to all of them is that they require your response to be a binary variable. Mine is not but I could produce a binary one with multiple entrances for each species. However, if I do that I most likely run into the problem that the number of rows in my analysis dataset is much larger than the number of tips in my phylogenetic tree! Now what are my options to do this analysis right?

In short I need a phylogenetic logistic regression taking a two-column variable as response (no. of successes, no. of failures), and which supports both continuous and categorical explanatory variables.

Answer (score 2):

Most phylogenetic comparative methods (including the method implemented in `phyloglm`) are designed to deal with species means. Here are two options you could consider:

1. Turn your counts of successes and failures into a vector of proportions, and model those with PGLS or phyloglm (depending on how the proportions are distributed, one of these options might work). It would be nice if there were an option to weight species based on sample size, but unfortunately I don't think there is.
2. Use [phylogenetic generalized linear mixed models](http://search.r-project.org/library/pez/html/pglmm.html). This may be preferred as preserves all of the information in your data, rather than erasing information about sample size as the first option does.